# Show Vaadin Framework Version

Tags: vaadin

Having installed Vaadin as an Eclipse Plugin several months ago, how do I find out which version of the Vaadin Framework is currently installed on my machine?

Comment: If you are using Maven, just check the version as described in your pom.xml. That is for your own project of course, not for the latest version the plugin supports.

Comment: Also, what you installed in Eclipse is probably the [Vaadin-eclipse-plugin](https://vaadin.com/eclipse) which helps your work with the Vaadin framework, but it's not the framework itself. The framework (a [set of jars aka dependencies](https://vaadin.com/maven#dependencies)) is not "installed" on your machine per se (at the very least you could have multiple versions downloaded in your local maven repo), but it's bundled with (or included) your project, so that's where you have to look for its version (maven pom, gradle build, ivy build file, etc).

Comment: Thanks @Morfic. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so I can accept it as the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all we need to differentiate between the 2 key concepts at hand:

- [Vaadin framework](https://vaadin.com/framework): a set of [libraries](https://vaadin.com/maven#dependencies) (or dependencies, or jars) that are used to develop rich internet applications. They'll be packaged with your application and deployed in a *web server*
- [Vaadin Eclipse plugin](https://vaadin.com/eclipse): a utility designed specifically for Eclipse to help you develop using the Vaadin framework

So, while it is true that the plugin can help you get started with developing a Vaadin application, eg creating a maven project from a prototype, it has almost nothing to do with the Vaadin version (almost because probably a certain version of the plugin will be compatible with a limited range of framework versions).

On the other hand, each project that uses the Vaadin framework, will include these dependencies somehow.

- if you chose to manually download the [zipped files](https://vaadin.com/releases) and place the jars in your project, they should contain the version in their name eg `vaadin-server-8.0.6.jar`. And even if they've been renamed, you can open the jar (they're just zip files) and inside the `META-INF` folder you'll see a `MANIFEST.MF` file which you can open with your favourite text editor and check the version, eg: [image: Manifest]
- if you're using some dependency management mechanism such as [maven](https://vaadin.com/maven#dependencies) (or ivy, gradle, etc) then you can look in the specific build file for the referenced version, eg:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

In conclusion, a Vaadin version is not exactly installed on your PC (you can have multiple versions downloaded in your local maven repo), but rather a certain version is used in a project, and you should look inside that project to figure out which one exactly is being used.